# MVVM: Bind ContentControl to CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ContentControl` that I want to bind it's `Content` property to `IsChecked` property of `CheckBox`.
I am using MVVM, as an idea I thought of doing this:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding CurrentTemplate}"/>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsNewCustumor}"/>
```

And in the view model I would listen for the `IsNewCustumor` property to change and assign the corresponding `DataTemplate` to the `CurrentTemplate` property, but I think that would involve using views in the view model which is not `MVVM`.
Another idea is to write a converter class, which I don't know how exactly should I implement it.

So can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to switch the template based on the value of the property `IsNewCustomer`. One way to achieve this, is using a style trigger. The advantage is, that it is purely XAML and easy to read:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNewCustomer}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="Set the template for new customers here">
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="Set the template for not new customers here">
        </Style>
    <ContentControl.Style>
<ContentControl>
```

Comment: Impressive way of  thinking. Thank I added a few modifications, since I wanted to bind directly to the CheckBox. Thanks a lot.